# How Do i Create a New Instance of a Contract

Tags: web3js

i am trying to figure out how i can deploy a new instance of a contract and setting some values by calling some of its methods.

i am trying to follow the example on the official docs website: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#

```
const comment = new web3.eth.Contract(Comment.abi, { from: coinbase });

// comment object is available here. all properties at this point seem to be defined. the value is not null here.
console.log('comment:', comment);

comment.deploy()
    .send({ from: coinbase })
    .then(console.log);
```

but i get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null
```

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it out.  I too found that the documentation was less than crystal-clear.

Answer (score 2):

i found the answer:

the solution was to pass in the bytecode to the `deploy` method.

then i recieved another error about insufficient gas. so in the `send` method i set some gas.

```
import commentContract from '../build/contracts/Comment.json';

const comment = new web3.eth.Contract(Comment.abi, { from: coinbase });

comment.deploy({ data: commentContract.bytecode })
    .send({ from: coinbase, gas: 1500000 })
    .then(console.log);
```

this now works.

Comment: May I suggest using truffle-contract though.

Comment: that seems to be a much better way of doing this. thanks for the advice.

Answer (score -2):

you need to instantiate it with .at(address)

So add

```
const commentInstance = comment.at(contractaddres)
```

Here's an example: [getContract.js](https://github.com/kyriediculous/dapp-tutorial/blob/master/src/util/getContract.js)

```
  let casinoContract = web3.eth.contract(ABI)
let casinoContractInstance = casinoContract.at(address)
```

Comment: i dont have an address. because it hasn't been deployed. maybe my question was not clear. i want to deploy a new instance of a contract to the blockchain.